# Swift: How to reference local image in NSURL

Tags: swift, image, nsurl, local-files

I have a code which loads some thumbnails from articles retrieved online and places them into an `Article` object. It looks like the following:

```
            for article in newArticlesArray {
                let url: String
                if let myGroup = article["group"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>, let myThumbnail = myGroup["thumbnail"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>, let myURL = myThumbnail["url"] as? String{
                    url = myURL
                }
                else{
                    url = "file://no-thumbnail.png"
                }

            let a = Article(t: article["title"] as! String,
                                    da: article["pubDate"] as! String,
                                    de: newDesc,
                                    th: NSURL(string: url)!,
                                    l: NSURL(string: article["link"] as! String)!)
                    articlesArray.addObject(a)
```

However the issue arises when an article does not have a thumbnail and hence I have to use a local image. The local file for no thumbnail is called `no-thumbnail.png`, however I cannot seem to find a simple guide online on how to actually reference a local file, in this case a .png image, through the usage of an NSURL in swift.

Looking for somebody to share some insight into this.

**Solution**

For people interested the solution is as follows:

```
let th = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("no-thumbnail", withExtension: "png")
url = th!.absoluteString
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "no-thumbnail", withExtension: "png")`

Comment: Had to do a slight edit to your code, but worked perfectly! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The syntax has changed a bit for **Swift 4**:

`let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "imageName", withExtension: "png")`